# C# | Почему проверка enum со switch ведёт себя странно?

Tags: c#, switch, enum

Я использую приложение СолоЛеарн для программирования, и там есть кодинг как пвп. И задался один вопрос, в котором нужно определить какой будет вывод кода. Там в коде создаётся enum **Elements**. В методе **Main** создаётся переменная, со значением 0. После инициализации этой переменной проверяется с оператором **switch** значение **Elements.Mg**. С помощью кейсов проверяется значение. Если значение является **Elements.K** или **Elements.Ca**, то переменной, которую мы инициализировать присваивается значение 1-2. А некоторые кейсы пустые. Итог кода - он выводит число 2 (из нашей переменной). Почему и как и что за фигня?
[image: Код]

P.s.: извиняюсь что скриншотом. На телефоне при переписывания кода мог сделать ошибку.

Comment: `switch (Elements.Mg)` совпадает с `case Elements.Mg`. Вроде никаких разночтений.

Comment: Некоторые кейсы не пустые. `Na` и `K` - один кейс. `Mg` и `Ca` - тоже один кейс.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, судя потому что вы сказали кейсы элементы Na, K должны вернуть 1 и сломать switch оператор

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov и кстати, если же по нашему свитч оператору Elements.Mg был бы верен, то ниже его был бы неверен

Comment: `Elements.Mg != Elements.Ca`

Comment: Так, давайте по порядку, вы пишете `switch (Elements.Mg)` - то есть входной элемент `Mg`, далее у вас идут условия "Если входное значение `Na` или `K`, то  `group = 1`, если `Mg` или `Ca`, то `group = 2`. Собственно, чего тут удивляться? Входное значение `Mg`, подходит под `case Elements.Mg: group = 2;`. То, что у вас "пустые кейсы", это означает что "телом кейса" будет то, что ниже. То есть у вас к примеру `Na` и `K` - используют `group = 1;`, а `Mg` и `Ca` - `group = 2;`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо вам большое за подробное объяснение. А как закончить вопрос?

Comment: @GamerDreemurr_X Дать ответ и отметить его правильным)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо большое)

Comment: Я даже не знаю как ответить, я не особо понял как работает свитч оператор. Лучше уж буду использовать c# 8.0 свитч выражение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Раз уж не очень поняли, то я попытаюсь обьяснить поподробнее.
Обьекты enum которым не присваиваются значение по дефолту будет присваиваться целочисленное число начиная с нуля. То есть:

```
    enum Elements
    {
        Na, // На самом деле равен 0
        K, // На самом деле равен 1
        Mg = 12, 
        Ca // На самом деле равен 13, т.к. после 12 - 13
    }
```

Получается что не важно присвоили ли мы значению телу enum, он будет автоматически выставляться.
Вы делаете условие `switch(Elemenets.Mg)` который на самом деле равен 2, то есть выполнится то условие которое равно 2. В switch есть возможность делать вложенные кейсы, то есть если условие попадает в кейс в котором есть другой кейс, то этот кейс тоже выполниться. К примеру

```
switch (2)
        {
            case 2:
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("Кейс 1");
                break;
        }
```

На консоль выведится `Кейс 1`, т.к. условие попадает в кейс, в котором находится кейс, тут особо задумываться не нужно. И у вас тоже условие попадает в `case Elements.Mg` в котором находится кейс `Elements.Ca`, который присваивает значие переменной `group` равной 2, именно поэтому на консоль выводится 2. Надеюсь всё подробоно обьяснил, если остануться вопросы, спрашивайте.

Comment: Спасибо большое) Про перечисления я знаю, я вот только не знал что в шарпе можно сделать несколько кейсов с одним телом.

Comment: @aepot Да вы правы, я ошибся, отредактировал.

Comment: Ну это скорее не "вложенный кейс", а "альтернативный кейс", просто такая форма записи.

Answer (score 3):

Я кажется понял как работает свитч оператор.
На языке руби можно записать так:

```rb
X = 6

case X
when 1, 2, 3, 4:
    puts "1-4"
when 5, 6, 7:
    puts "5-7"
```

На шарпе же можно написать вот-так:

```cs
int X = 6;

switch (X)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
        WriteLine("1-4");
        break;
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
        WriteLine ("5-7");
        break;
}
```

Если я что-то не учел, напишите в комментариях.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch - там много еще всякого. А еще есть вот такое - https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression